# Can Google Data Studio call a MySQL stored procedure with parameters and consume the result set?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, looker-studio

All--
  (Ducking to avoid the flames....)  I would like to use Google Data Studio to create simple reports from MySQL data.  For each of several reports, I have written a corresponding MySQL stored procedure that has a single parameter, pEndDate (a CHAR(10) string in the format yyyy-MM-dd).  It seems simple enough to use MySQL tables and views as data sources for Google Data Studio, but I haven't seen any documentation or blog posts re: stored procedures.  Any and all comments are welcome.

Thanks,

Matthew P. Seltzer

P.S.  I am running MySQL 5.6 on Windows 10 Pro.

MPS

Comment: I haven't tried this but it looks from here: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031?hl=en as if you can specify a 'Custom Query', could that perhaps call the stored procedure (CALL MYPROC) & get your result set back? Alternatively you could perhaps somehow leverage a Google Sheets layer in between.

Comment: If all else fails, I get mysql data from my hosted cpanel into GDS via a little bit of php which returns the result set for any sql statement in csv format to a Google Sheet which is then accessed by GDS (the database is v small, not particularly private, and accessed with read and execute permission only). I've just tried this with a test stored procedure call and it worked fine (at least as far as returning the right csv content).

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm able to create a datasource by calling a stored procedure, but once i'm trying to create a report from this source it failed with a query syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You may try making the stored procedure a function then you can call that in a SELECT, you may need to experiment a bet with getting the function to trigger before the datasource selecting from the views and tables, but it's worth a shot.